# Error.html page code showing up in meta description of my homepage

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, meta, sitecore8, sitecore9

Html code is showing up inside the meta description on my google result for the hompage of my site. This only happens on the homepage; all of the other pages show their correct meta description. How can HTML show up in our meta description?

My site is set up using the Sitecore, which is a .NET CMS platform.

[image]

The code is from our error.html page, which should only be seen when an error 500 occurs, the following image is our web.config file showing the set up:

[image]

The meta description has been set up on the home page. Other pages have the exact same setup, and their meta descriptions show up fine in google.

[image]

Can anyone give any suggestions on why the meta description is showing the error 500 page?

Comment: The homepage probably throws a 500 error when it's hit by the Google Crawler. Why that is you have to find out by logging and elimination of suspect blocks of code.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but is that really what the html looks like? It's malformed if that's what's on the page. Missing stuff before DOCTYPE (`<!`)and meta tags not closed properly. Prob doesn't matter, but just in case.

Comment: Do you have custom error page for sitecore in sitecore pipeline?

Comment: @Mhoque Yeah, the code that shows up is from the error 500 page.